# Perl / Net::SNMP : script too slow, need to optimize

Tags: perl, optimization, snmp

I would like to optimize my perl script because it is a bit slow for displaying informations about the network.
I don't know what can be changed or ameliorated to boost the script execution.
I manipulate several hashes, to get : mac add, index, etc... I think it's a bit heavy, but no other choice.
Moreover, I do a lot of SNMP request and the handling of errors is maybe not great.
I copy/paste my script and its module.
Thanks in advance for reading my code.

It takes in args :

1. interface name (ex. FastEthernet0/9 or FastEthernet0/1...)
2. hostname : ip of the switch
3. community (often =public)

Hope this is comprehensible.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Getopt::Long;
    use SnmpUtil;
    use AdresseMac;
    use Net::SNMP;
    use Net::SNMP::Interfaces;

    my $ifname;
    my $hostname;
    my $community;
    my $version = 1;

    GetOptions( "ifname=s"  => \$ifname,
                "host=s"    => \$hostname,
                "community=s"   => \$community,
                "protocol:s"    => \$version);

    my $interfaces = Net::SNMP::Interfaces->new(Hostname => $hostname, Community => $community);
    my $inter = $interfaces->interface($ifname);
    #Get interface $ifname
    my $ifindex = $inter->index();
    #Vitesse
    my $vitesse = $inter->ifHighSpeed();
    #Alias
    my $ifalias = $inter->ifAlias();

    #Seek for VLANs
    my $vlan_trouve;

    #Listing all VLANS
    my $vmVlan = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68.1.2.2.1.2"; #OID of vlan table
    my $vlans = SnmpUtil->new($hostname, $community);
    my %vl = $vlans->requeteTable($vmVlan);

    $vlans->deconnexion();

    #Get the good VLAN corresponding to index interface
    $vlan_trouve = $vl{$ifindex};

    #Listing : port VLAN <-> @mac
    my $dot1dTpFdbAddress = "1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1";
    my $dot = SnmpUtil->new($hostname, $community."@".$vlan_trouve);
    my %dot1address = $dot->requeteTable($dot1dTpFdbAddress);

    #Listing : numPortBridge <-> port VLAN
    my $dot1dTpFdbPort = "1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2";
    my %portdot = reverse($dot->requeteTable($dot1dTpFdbPort));

    #Listing : num Port bridge <-> ID port switch
    my $dot1dBasePortIfIndex = "1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2";
    my %dotindex = reverse($dot->requeteTable($dot1dBasePortIfIndex));

    #Duplex (auto, half or full)
    my $oid_cisco_duplex = "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.2.1.19.".$ifindex;
    my $duplex = $dot->requete($oid_cisco_duplex);
    if ($duplex==1) {
        $duplex= "Auto";
    }
    elsif ($duplex==2) {
        $duplex = "Half";
    }
    elsif ($duplex==3) {
        $duplex= "Full";
    }
    #Close connection
    $dot->deconnexion();

    #Go back up, to find mac add
    my $numportbridge = $dotindex{$ifindex};
    if (!defined($numportbridge)) {
        print "Erreur : $ifindex not found in list : num Port bridge <-> ID port switch\n";
        exit 2;
    }
    my $portVlan = $portdot{$numportbridge};
    if (!defined($portVlan)) {
        print "Erreur : $numportbridge not found in list : numPortBridge <-> ports du VLAN\n";
        exit 3;
    }
    my $add = uc($dot1address{$portVlan});
    if (!defined($add)) {
        print "Erreur : $portVlan not found in list : ports du VLAN <-> \@mac\n";
        exit 4;
    }
    $add =~ s/^0X//g;
    printf "<b>Port : $ifname</b><br/>Index $ifindex on VLAN : $vlan_trouve<br/>\@mac : $add<br/>Speed=$vitesse Mbps Alias=$ifalias<br/>Duplex: $duplex\n";
```

Here's SnmpUtil.pm :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SNMP;
package SnmpUtil;

our ($session, $error);

sub new {
  my ($classe, $hostname, $community) = @_;
  my $this = {
    "hostname"  => $hostname,
    "community" => $community
  };
  bless($this, $classe);
  $this->{connexion} = $this->connexion;
  return $this;
}

sub connexion {
    my ($this) = @_;

    ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
        -hostname  => $this->{hostname},
        -community => $this->{community},
        -version   => "1",
        -timeout   => 3,
    );
    request_error_connexion() if (!defined($session));
}

sub request_error_connexion {   
    my ($this) = @_;
    print "Erreur : can't connect to host\n";
    print "Erreur : $error\n";
    if ($error =~ /The argument "-community" is unknown/)
        {
                # protocol SNMP version 3 not working 
                exit 3;  # code ret final = 3*256 = 768
        }
    else
    {
        exit 1; # code retour final = 1*256 = 256
    }
}

sub request_error {
        my ($this) = @_;
        print "Error : no answer from host\n";
        printf "Erreur : %s\n",$session->error;
        if ($session->error =~ /No response from remote host/)
        {
                #host ok, bad community or host refuse connection
                $session->close;
                exit 2; # code retour final = 2*256 = 512
        }
        else
        {
                #can not find table
                $session->close;
                exit 4; # code retour final = 4*256 = 1024
        }
}

sub requeteTable {
    my ($this, $oid) = @_;
    my $result = $session->get_table( -baseoid => $oid );
    request_error() if (!defined($result));
    my %tab = ();

    foreach my $i (Net::SNMP::oid_lex_sort(keys %{$result})) {
        my $index = $i;
        $index =~ s/$oid.//;
        $tab{ $index } = $result->{$i};  
        #print $index."--".$result->{$i}."\n";
    }

    return %tab;
}

sub requete {
    my ($this, $oid) = @_;
    my $result = $session->get_request($oid);
    request_error() if (!defined($result));
    return $result->{$oid}; 
}

sub deconnexion {
    my ($this) = @_;
    $session->close();
}

1;
```

AdresseMac.pm module is useless, it's just to convert dec to hex & vice-versa.

Thanks for your help,
big reward for the one who find optimization ;)

PS: forgot to say, I work on cisco switch 2960.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not like this answer, but one of the reasons that Net-SNMP supports a perl module (called just *SNMP*) written using C-bindings rather than the all-in-perl module implementation done in *Net::SNMP* is that the C-bindings are significantly faster.  Giovanni Marzot, who wrote the initial implementation of the Net-SNMP C-binding binding, measured the C/perl-binding implementation to be up to 10 times faster than the all-perl version.  And if you starting getting into the authenticated/encrypted SNMPv3 then it gets even faster.  I don't *know* if this is the source of your problems, however.  Just a data point.  A perl profiler would really let you know.

Another point to consider: if you're querying lots of hosts, think about architecting your code so that you can send multiple queries out at a time using asynchronous requests and using GetBulk requests using SNMPv2c as well.  These two optimizations will greatly increase the speed as well.

**Updated** with links per request:

- Net-SNMP: http://www.net-snmp.org/ and download: http://www.net-snmp.org/download.html .

  - The net-snmp toolkit comes with it's perl module.  Configure Net-SNMP using --with-perl-modules
- Net-SNMP's perl FAQ: http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ:Perl
- A mildly out of date man page: http://metacpan.org/pod/SNMP

Note that Net-SNMP has a gettable() function you may be interested in that does lots of optimizations.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your post, I only use SNMP v1, they don't want to use newer version of SNMP. Have you got some links for using the faster SNMP lib with Perl ?